# Multiple conditions- if value between range display corresponding value

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I tried to figure it out by myself and with the internet but I need your help.

I need to check a value is in few ranges and assign in the cell the corresponding value:

*** all the numbers are integers**

If the value is 0, display 1

if the value between 1 to 3, display 2

if the value between 4 to 6, display 3

if the value between 7 to 10, display 4

if the value is above 10, display 5

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF Function

```
=IF(B2=0,1,if(B2<=3,2,if(B2<=6,3,if(B2<=10,4,5))))
```

This assumes the value you are checking is in B2 AND that it is a positive integer (ie, no -1 or 1.5)

VLOOKUP Function

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$6,2,1)
```

- B2 value you are checking
- F2:G6 is the table of break points (F) and values to be displayed (G)

Build a table with the first column being your break points and a column adjacent to it being the values you want to display.  In this case your breakpoints would be 0,3,6,10 and we need to add 11 for the values greater than 10.  This method assumes positive values and with the exception of the 11 breakpoint could be used for decimals as well as integers.  The current problem is values between 10 and 11 would display as 4 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Two more alternatives if you wanted to do it with a single formula without a separate lookup table:-

```
=MATCH(A2,{0,1,4,7,11})

=HLOOKUP(A2,{0,1,4,7,11;1,2,3,4,5},2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
=COUNTIFS(Range, "condition1", Range, "condition2")**
```

Example (finding total numbers lies between 25 to 21 in  range `J9:J110`)

```
=COUNTIFS(J9:J110, "<=25", J9:J110, ">=21")**
```